# ADF Mobile send data using POST method

Tags: post, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I need to know how we can send data by consuming RESTful services using **POST** method in Oracle ADF Mobile. I have used **GET** method and it works fine. But now I need to send some data using **POST**. How can I achieve it? or How I can use *RestServiceAdapter* to accomplish this task?

Please provide tutorial or some steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the REST data control you can assign methods to the various HTML methods. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ujo8c-2UTo

Comment: Good one! I will try to do it using .amx pages instead of .jsf. Thanks for help.